# Microsoft Fakes generator fails to load PCL .dll

Tags: unit-testing, windows-store-apps, microsoft-fakes

To support testing in a Windows Store MVVM application, I've split the Models and ViewModels out into a separate PCL targeting Windows Store and .NET 4.5 only. I have a .NET 4.5 unit test project which has a reference to the Model/ViewModel PCL and have it generating a fakes assembly of that .dll

This all works fine until I try to build the project, at which time the unit test library fails to build with this in the output:

```
framework assembly path: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\PublicAssemblies
output path: C:\Project\Project.UnitTest\FakesAssemblies
intermediate path: C:\Project\Project.UnitTest\obj\Release\Fakes
Fakes: 1 (1 .fakes files)
    Fakes\Project.Portable.fakes
fakes tool: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v11.0\Fakes\fakes.x86.exe
Microsoft Fakes v11.0.51106.1 - .NET v4.0.30319
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation 2007-2010. All rights reserved.

fakes
  code : assembly C:\Project\Project.Portable\bin\Release\Project.Portable.dll failed to load properly
fakes generator 1 errors, 0 warnings
result: error while loading the assembly (-1005 - 0xfffffc13)
Microsoft Fakes v11.0.51106.1 - .NET v4.0.30319
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation 2007-2010. All rights reserved.

fakes
code : assembly C:\Project\Project.Portable\bin\Release\Project.Portable.dll failed to load properly
fakes generator 1 errors, 0 warnings
```

If I run the fakes generator manually against the project from the command line, it succeeds.

I have seen some people with different issues generating fakes in build able to also do it by the command line but with different failures. I could directly reference the fakes .dll instead of generating it in build and make sure that I'm manually generating it each time the project changes, but this seems like a last resort to me.

Comment: Any chance you figured this out?  Experiencing the same issue...

Comment: Sorry, still completely stumped.

Comment: I actually did figure out my issue.  One of them assemblies that I had faked had a dependency that had a reference that was not correct.  I found this by removing all my refs, adding them one by one, and then creating the fake.  Also make sure you turn diagnostics on in the fakes config.  Good luck.